# Set all rows except 1

Tags: mysql

I have a flag in my database called published, I set this to 1 for a published row. My question is , is there a way to set all other rows to 0 and set a particular row to 1 with just one query.

At the moment im using:

```
$db->query("UPDATE my_table SET published = '0'");
$db->query("UPDATE my_table SET published = '1' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE my_table SET published = IF (id = $id,1,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CASE Statement

```
UPDATE my_table
SET published = CASE
    WHEN id = '$id' THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, there's no boolean type (conditions return an integer), so this works too :

```
UPDATE my_table
SET published = (id = $id);
```

`id = $id` returns 0 if $id is different than id, else 1.